# Using grid for header and images but one image now is on top of/hiding the other

Tags: css, image, css-grid

Instead of coming out side by side the second img now hides the other one behind it, not sure what is causing that. Haven't used grid areas in awhile, but used some of the same structure I used for something else, that had been successful, so can't understand why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

```css
#intro article{
 background: #FFE121;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-areas: 
  "a a"
  "b c";
 grid-column-gap: 50px;
 
}

#intro article h2{
 grid-area: a;
}

#intro article:first-of-type img{
 grid-area: b;
}

#intro article:last-of-type img{
 grid-area: c;
}

#intro h2{
 text-align: center;
 color:#037272;
}


#intro p{
 flex:100%;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding:20px 40px;
}
```

```html
 <section id="intro">
  <article>
  
   <img src="images/c1.JPG" alt="c 1">

   <h2>This year we welcome ...</h2>

   <img src="images/c2.JPG" alt="c 2">
   
  </article>
   
  
  <p>By popular demand...</p>
  
 </section>
```

Comment: You're not selecting the right element try it like this 
`#intro article img:first-of-type`
`#intro article img:last-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector `#intro article:first-of-type img` is incorrect, it should be `#intro article img:first-of-type`.

The same goes for `#intro article:last-of-type img`.

```css
#intro article{
 background: #FFE121;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-areas: 
  "a a"
  "b c";
 grid-column-gap: 50px;
 
}

#intro article h2{
 grid-area: a;
}

#intro article img:first-of-type{
 grid-area: b;
}

#intro article img:last-of-type{
 grid-area: c;
}

#intro h2{
 text-align: center;
 color:#037272;
}


#intro p{
 flex:100%;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding:20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <article>
  
   <img src="" alt="c 1">

   <h2>This year we welcome ...</h2>

   <img src="" alt="c 2">
   
  </article>
   
  
  <p>By popular demand...</p>
  
 </section>
```